# How to decrease the instance size in Amazon EBS without shutting down the instance?(Linux System)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I need to decrease the size in Amazon EBS instance without shutting down the system. If the instance size is 32 GB, I want to make this to 16GB.

Is it possible? Please guide me.

Comment: EBS is a storage and cannot decrease but only can increase. If you really want to do that then make a snap and prepare smaller EBS, attach and recover. I am not gurantee this would work or not. Anyway, I was also tried to decrease the volmue size and there inn't a way without stopping EC2

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-how-to-extend-aws-ebs-volumes-with-no-downtime-ec7d9e82426e

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to do this? If it is purely to save money, then the 16GB of storage would only save $1.60/month.

Comment: @Adiii increasing is not a matter and there is no problem. Only decreasing is the matter.

Comment: Money is not a problem for me, I was just created an instance with 32 GB but right now I am using around 15 GB of data. I want to reduce the instance size without shut downing my system. In future I will increase this as when I am required. Is that possible please

Comment: Thank you lamanus . Will try then